# Grid.Mvc column details on click?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Am trying to implement the Grid.Mvc details as shown on their page and 'Sample Screenshot'  at  http://gridmvc.codeplex.com/

Here it shows "Order details" on the right side, from clicking on one of the rows? The goal is to implement this, add ActionLinks in there to take action such as Edit/Details/Delete just as the original bootstrap/Entity Framework index() view has.

The question is how to wire it up properly,

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Named("ordersGrid").Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add(model => model.ID).Titled("ID").SetWidth(10);
    columns.Add(model => model.CustomerNumber).Titled("Cust #").SetWidth(10);

}).WithPaging(10)

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-9">
    <h4>
        Order details
    </h4>
    <div id="order-content">
        <p class="muted">
            Select order to display detailed infomation
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
$(function () {
    pageGrids.ast.onRowSelect(function (e) {
        alert(e.row.ID);

        $.post(e.row, function (data) {
            //if (data.Status <= 0) {
            //    alert(data.Message);
            //    return;
            //}
            $("#order-content").html(e.row);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is ok, it was not triggering on the row click, because a reference was needed within the /Shared/_Layout.cshtml, had to download the jquery.min.js and rename it to match;

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now its triggering and any row clicked gets the alert dialog with the number of the ID.

But in the $.post(e.row, function (data) {   this is not filling in any details within the div named "#order-content",  UPDATED: fixed the syntax in the function and its working.

```
 <script>
$(function () {
    pageGrids.ast.onRowSelect(function (e) {
        alert(e.row.ID);

        $.post("/astroidreports/details/" +e.row.ID,
            function(data){

                $("#order-content").html(data);
            })
        });
    });
```

Comment: Not sure what your specific question is, but basically the javascript event pageGrids.ordersGrid.onRowSelect is firing causing an ajax call that returns a partial view (_OrderInfo) which is then inserted in to the div to the right of the grid. So you should be able to add your own action links to _OrderInfo.

Comment: I have the grid, but cannot get the $(function () to "see" this grid's onRowSelect, to be able to insert that data.  I added an alert("clicked"); hoping to see when it fires, into the function.  so far its not.

Answer (score 1):

Your grid name doesn't match the javascript:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Named("ordersGrid")  <--- you name it here, change to "ast"
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add(model => model.ID).Titled("ID").SetWidth(10);
    columns.Add(model => model.CustomerNumber).Titled("Cust #").SetWidth(10);

}).WithPaging(10)

<script>
$(function () {
    pageGrids.ast.onRowSelect(function (e) {    <--- expects grid name "ast"
        alert(e.row.ID);

        $.post(e.row, function (data) {
            //if (data.Status <= 0) {
            //    alert(data.Message);
            //    return;
            //}
            $("#order-content").html(e.row);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I had been changing this around, but did manage to get this to work just fine after adding the other reference in the _Layout.cshtml file for the gridmvc.min.js  and i thought the code had been fully updated, but thank you for correcting it here.